# How to handle tags in a noSQL database

Tags: firebase, database-design, firebase-realtime-database, database, nosql

I have a noSQL db with products. These products obviously have some characteristics and I can filter the products out by their properties.

How does this work with tags? More specifically, how should I structure the nodes such that I can filter out items with a specific tag?

**Firebase**

Follow up if you are familiar with Firebase .equalTo(): how would I structure my FB db and how would I query out items with a specic tag?

One thing I was thinking of is to have seperate properties for the nodes, e.g.:

```
   $productId
       /tag_1
       /tag_2
```

But then I have to filter or query multiple times. How can this be overcome or are there other ways?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're putting the `tags` underneath the `products`. Try flipping it.

```
$tagId
   /$productId
```

Now you can find a product by a tag without a query.

```
// https://<my-firebase-app>.firebaseio.com/tags/{tag}/{productId}
var ref = new Firebase('url').child('tags').child($tagId).child($productId);
```

The JSON would look like this:

```
{
   "tags":{
      "kinda_cool":{
         "product_3":true,
         "product_6":true
      },
      "super_cool":{
         "product_1":true,
         "product_2":true,
         "product_4":true,
         "product_5":true
      }
   }
}
```

Rather than true you could store any other relevant information. But having the `$productId` as the key you can easily retrieve a product by it's tag.

Comment: That sounds a lot of work in the sense that if the changes or adds a tag it needs to be updated as well? Requires a lot tracking? If I have 5 tags then thar product returns 5 times

Comment: Yes, consider this an index. It may be a little bit more maintenance but it's the one of the most performant ways to find a product by it's tag. You can also use multi-path updates to keep everything consistent. https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-10-07-how-to-keep-your-data-consistent.html

Comment: Ah I think I see what you mean. There doesn't have to be any changes because you're not using the `products/tags` location anymore. Just this new index.

Comment: If this answer meets your criteria can you please mark it as accepted. It's good to keep the answered queue clear. If not let me know what else is needed.

Comment: @DavidEast how do I do this with mongoDB? As it does not support key names (i.e. "tags")